# Is it OK to expand someone else's answer from an old question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, flags, plagiarism

So here I was, a new user hoping to help Stack Overflow, started my way on answering some minimalistic questions.

I got into this question on C: [How to make an output function similar to Python's in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044070/how-to-make-an-output-function-similar-to-pythons-in-c)

I liked it and upvoted it and even went to answering it. Then I find [Antti Haapala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044070/how-to-make-an-output-function-similar-to-pythons-in-c/64044782#64044782) showing a basic solution using macros. I went to use the same one but expanded.

> Just search for my answer, I'm sick of copy-pasting these links.

Now that I posted it, I feel guilty that my answer will get downvoted, or worse, flagged for plagiarism (even though it's clear I gave him credit).

Because of this, I'm wondering if it's okay to expand someone else's answer in an older question.

**Questions:**

1. Is it OK to take someone's answer and expand it further (while crediting the original author)?
2. Can I do it in any answer, or do I have to stick "from scratch"?

Comment: Here is the link to the OP's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65040947/13736952

Answer (score -9):

In my decision, I think while giving the original creator credit from the answer, expanding it doesn't do that much harm.

While yes, downvotes could eventually occur on your answer, at least you didn't plagiarize.

I guess you can expand an answer you find or just edit that answer.

As for the 2nd question, I don't think you should do this too much. If you can do it from scratch, it's better that way, while still helping the asker.